# Compare 2 Lists with Except() Method but it didnt work

Tags: c#, list, merge, compare, except

I would like to compare with the Except Method 2 lists. Objects are stored in these lists.

If I use the Except method, nothing is filtered, although there are identical objects.

My goal:

I want to have all objects in the list "chkpoints" that are not in the list "chkpointslist".

What is the best way to do this or what am I doing wrong?

```
List<checkpoint> chkpoints = new List<checkpoint>();
List<checkpoint> chkpointslist = new List<checkpoint>();
chkpointslist = database.loadChecklistpoints(checklistid);
chkpoints = database.loadCheckpoint(type);
chkpoints = chkpoints.Except(chkpointslist).ToList();
```

Comment: Does `checkpoint` override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`?  If not it will do reference equality meaning two instances of the class with the same value will not be equal.  There is an overload of `Except` where you can pass a `IEqualityComparer<checkpoint>` to tell it how to determine if two `checkpoint` objects are equal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`Enumerable.Except`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.except?view=netframework-4.8) uses the default equality comparer to compare values. So, if your `checkpoint` class doesn't have an [`IEquatable`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.iequatable-1?view=netframework-4.8), all of your `checkpoint` instances will just be read as unique.

From the .NET docs:

> If you want to compare sequences of objects of some custom data type, you have to implement the `IEquatable<T>` generic interface in a helper class.

There are examples on how to create an IEquatable helper class on the `Enumerable.Except` docs (linked above).